# How to localize Telerik MVC Grid Enum filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a filter for an Enum column but I need to localize the text showed for the Enum items in the dropdown. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [following example](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-filter-ui.aspx).  It will get you started.  Basically, Telerik MVC Grid doesn't support configuring the filter area fluently.  You have to hack it up with javascript.